# selenium instagram bot but the xpath is not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram, bots

First I thought that the webdriver is not able to find the xpath but even if include implicit wait. it still throws me the error

```
def login(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/accounts/login/']")
    login_button.click()
    time.sleep(6)
    user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
    user_name_elem.clear()
    user_name_elem.send_keys(self.username)
    passworword_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
    passworword_elem.clear()
    passworword_elem.send_keys(self.password)
    passworword_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(6)
```

> File "crawl_profile.py", line 35, in login
>       user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 752, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 192, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   missing or invalid 'entry.level'   (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174
>   (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6
>   x86_64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your chromedriver.exe to latest version.

Now you are using old chromedriver version
**(Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174)**

You need to use :
**(ChromeDriver 2.39)
(Supports Chrome v66-68)**

Please refe this link :- [chroemdriver latest version updates](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)